# Append form values to hidden XML string on post

Tags: php, jquery, xml

I am posting a form to a remote server and have to send over an XML formatted string as a hidden field, containing the entered info. Im struggling to append the input values entered to the XML string, E.g.:

```
            <input type="text" name="firstname" id="fname" />   
            <input type="text" name="lastname" id="sname"  />
```

The XML is as such:

```
<input type="hidden" name="parameters" value="<request><first_name>Test User</first_name> <surname>XXXX</surname></request>"/>
```

How can I with PHP ideally, on POST, apply the values entered in the inputs to the XML string, so firstname and surname are posted as entered by the user?

I tried Jquery but it broke the XML string.

Many Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4):

I think you need to use java script to manipulate parameters value.

Sample example

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<script language="javascript">
function callme()
{
    document.getElementById('parameters').value="<request><first_name>"+document.getElementById('fname').value+"</first_name> <surname>"+document.getElementById('sname').value+"</surname></request>";
    document.getElementById('loginForm').submit();

}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form id="loginForm">
<input type="text" name="firstname" id="fname" />   
<input type="text" name="lastname" id="sname"  />
<input type="hidden" id="parameters" name="parameters" value=""/>
<input type="button" onclick="javascript:callme()" />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should do this server-side as malicious users could post anything. Having to escape your first and last name values is a lot easier than validating the correctness of your xml.

```
$first = htmlspecialchars($_GET['firstname']);
$last = htmlspecialchars($_GET['lastname']);

$xml = sprintf
(   '<request>
         <first_name>%s</first_name>
         <last_name>%s</last_name>
     </request>',
    $first, $last
);
```

There is no reason to do this in javascript unless you need that xml to be sent of to a different url by ajax.

**EDIT** This solution also works for people having javascript turned off (e.g no-script users).

Answer (score 0):

html -

```
<input type="text" name="firstname" id="fname" />   
<input type="text" name="lastname" id="sname"  />
<input type="hidden" id="parameters" />
<input type="button" name="click" id="button" value="button" />
```

Script - Use a parameter and set before submit e.g.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var parameters = "<request><first_name>YYYY</first_name> <surname>XXXX</surname></request>";
    $('#button').click(function(){
        parameters = parameters.replace('YYYY',$('#fname').val());
        parameters = parameters.replace('XXXX',$('#sname').val())
        $('#parameters').val(parameters);
        alert($('#parameters').val());
    });
});
```